# Как конвертировать файлы в base64 android?

Tags: android, base64

Пытаюсь сделать конвертирование файлов с телефона в base64. Пока вычитал что вроде как сразу файл конвертировать в base64 нельзя, и для начала нужно его перегнать в string а потом уже его можно будет конвертировать в base64. Но почему-то криво получается конвертировать например картинку в string, вот что получается (прикрепляю кусок потому что очень много знаков):

```
������JFIF����H��H��������C��           ����C����HH"����������������������������������  ����N������!1AQ"aq� 2�#B����$Rbr���%Cc��S����45s������������������������������������8������������!1A"Qaq�2R�����#�3B�CSb����������?����(A�7���,[    I=�+=�-�*�W���Ñ�K����w<}+N>ϝ�8��B��Ce��5���ؠ��)�P~B�,s��O+�4�y�@�UI�Pr��q��J�����N;�R~tPx�V��9�F�(m�g��=�?�@R������҈Z�{v�(�<�4Z��4  ��������m`�٠m �ց6���`��+i"���a�m��g=��ϑ��H"�CeF�CXFy����#2I�A>����a?3B������=�ށb�������������������4��44�Tx=�   .���tXch������< ��Q?j5.yb�0��+F:Eo�=�m���*������}�?�lrO�A*��{�V�Fs@��}�Ҭ'�)��(K8�{�x �@��e���Y@�BeK*^s@S��ǭ'h��y8��;i=ȣ����(ֱ�'���T�lTW��H����y�T�A4�jʿ�mٞR�~���^;�]D�}q�d�]�Z��$C�d�me;��Z�e(���t`�΢�K����~�S���BR��z/8Ȧ�#��X�����)�I�`8H�(��@�1ނ�wy�&;�G*95�����ʰ:�P*O�+^|E+=�>t$ *   ��qބ��BɣQ�>B�2��g��<ў줞(���'1�(���ɠ)ӻ�ʁ�$�:��ނ\��h*�<�
```

вот как я это делаю:

```
 public static String getFileContents(final File file) throws IOException {
        final InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        boolean done = false;

        while (!done) {
            final String line = reader.readLine();
            done = (line == null);

            if (line != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        }

        reader.close();
        inputStream.close();

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

в эту функцию я перекидываю файл с устройства. Есть два варианта - либо все работает так как нужно и все нормально, либо я нашел нерабочий способ и у меня все работает не так. Надеюсь на помощь и полезные советы.

Comment: С какой целью делаете? Если для отправки на сервер то дохлый номер

Comment: с целью последующей выгрузки на сервер, это попытка реализовать функцию прикрепления к письму файла, почему дохлый номер?

Comment: Картинка (судя по первым байтам -- jpg) это бинарный файл, а у вас используется код для тестовых файлов (`StringBuilder`), так что вам нужно будет считать файл в байтах и закодировать в base64, пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13109632/5909792

Comment: @gil9red, если я правильно понял ваш комментарий сначала нужно перегнать файл в массив байт а потом уже кодировать?

Comment: Да, кст, вот еще пример по вашей задаче: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37066216/5909792

Comment: Я делал так же на первых порах, память телефона очень быстро заканчивается. Отправляйте в виде multipart form data

Comment: для этого удобна библиотека okhttp3

Comment: @axmed2004, а можете более подробно объяснить, потому что не очень понятно?

Comment: @Andrew Goroshko, при кодировании картинок в base64, особенно если их больше 1, расходуется много ОЗУ, а у некоторых телефонов ее не очень много. ОС вынуждена загрузить в ОЗУ весь base64 код перед отправкой. а способ multipart позволяет отправлять большие файлы частями, и Вы не получите ошибку OutOfmemory. да и на сервере не нужно обратно перегонять код в картинку

Comment: а если мне нужно отправить файл например, а не только картинку? просто есть желание сделать прикрепление файлов например как в обычном почтовом приложении гмейл например или что-то в это роде

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что у меня получилось сделать:

```
public String convertFileToString(String pathOnSdCard) {
        String strFile = null;
        File file = new File(pathOnSdCard);

        try {

            byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);//Convert any file, image or video into byte array

            byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            fis.read(bytesArray); //read file into bytes[]
            fis.close();


            strFile = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);//Convert byte array into string

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return strFile;

    }
```

в итоге возвращается строка в составе которой есть мой файл. Возможно решение очень кривое и стремное, но оно мне помогло, и надеюсь что поможет таким же начинающим разработчикам как и я. В метод передаю путь до файла.

Comment: Вы файл два раза читаете и нигде не используете `bytesArray`

Comment: хм... а ведь и правда)) вероятнее всего второй раз его читать не нужно